# how to send a message in multicast group (wired to wireless)

Tags: c#-4.0, network-programming

my project is to let two devices communicate with each other, one is a laptop and the other one is a desktop, using Sockets class in c#. The laptop is connected to the router via wireless connection while the desktop is connected to LAN or Wired connection to the same router.

The problem is when i let my laptop send data to the desktop, the desktop does not received any data. But when i tried sending a message via another laptop connected via wireless connection it first laptop are able to receive the data send by the another laptop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections;

namespace gslib
{

public class StateObject
{
    private Socket m_socket;
    private byte[] m_data;
    private StringBuilder m_message;

    public StateObject()
    {
        m_message = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public Socket Socket
    { 
        set { m_socket = value; } 
        get { return m_socket; } 
    }
    public byte[] Data
    { 
        set { m_data = value; } 
        get { return m_data; } 
    }
    public StringBuilder Message
    {
        set { m_message = value; }
        get { return m_message; }
    }
}

public class GroupAgent
{
    private const int BUFFERSIZE = 4096;

    public GroupAgent()
    {
        m_ip = string.Empty;
        m_port = -1;
    }

    public GroupAgent(string ip, int port)
    {
        m_ip = ip;
        this.m_port = port;
    }

    #region decleration

    private string m_ip;
    private int m_port;

    #endregion

    #region events

    public delegate void MessageRecievedEventhandler(string message);
    public event MessageRecievedEventhandler MessageRecieved;

    #endregion

    #region private methods

    private byte[] trimByte(byte[] receive, int x)
    {
        List<byte> temp = new List<byte>();
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            temp.Add(receive[i]);
        }
        return temp.ToArray();
    }

    private void receive(Socket sock)
    {
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.Socket = sock;
        state.Data = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];

        sock.BeginReceive(state.Data, 0, BUFFERSIZE, SocketFlags.None, new    AsyncCallback(DoReceiveFrom), state);
    }

    private void DoReceiveFrom(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)iar.AsyncState;   
        try
        {                             
            int count = state.Socket.EndReceive(iar);

            byte[] temp = trimByte(state.Data, count);

            if (MessageRecieved != null)
            {
                MessageRecieved(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(temp));
            }

            state.Socket.BeginReceive(state.Data, 0, BUFFERSIZE, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(DoReceiveFrom), state);
        }
        catch 
        {
            state.Socket.BeginReceive(state.Data, 0, BUFFERSIZE, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(DoReceiveFrom), state);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region public properties

    public string _GroupIP
    {
        set { m_ip = value; }
        get { return m_ip; }
    }

    public int _Port
    {
        set { m_port = value; }
        get { return m_port; }        
    }

    #endregion

    #region public methods

    public void connect()
    {
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,
ProtocolType.Udp);
        sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 
ProtocolType.Udp);
        sock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _Port));

        sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new 
MulticastOption(IPAddress.Parse(_GroupIP), IPAddress.Any));
        sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, 
SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 2);

        receive(sock);           
    }

    public void connect(string m_ip, int port)
    {
        _GroupIP = m_ip;
        _Port = port;
        connect();
    }

    public void sendMessage(string message)
    {
        byte[] msg = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 
ProtocolType.Udp);

        sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new 
MulticastOption(IPAddress.Parse(_GroupIP)));
        sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, 
SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 2);

        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_GroupIP), _Port);
        sock.Connect(iep);

        sock.Send(msg);

        sock.Close();
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

What am i lacking here?. Do I have to set anything on my router?. Please reply

Answer (score 0):

```
sock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _Port));
```

The problem is here. That causes UDP to route the outgoing datagram according to the unicast IP routing tables, and if the routing table doesn't prefer the wireless route it won't be used. Bind it to an IP address of the local wifi interface.

Comment: when i bind it to a wireless interface i can no longer received or send data...

any suggestion on this one?.
**note im communicating using a multicast group IP**

by the way thanks for the reply.

Comment: To receive via all interfaces you have to join the group via all interfaces. INADDR_ANY isn't sufficient for that either.

Comment: Can u show me the proper way of joining a group via all interfaces? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What are the values for m_ip and port.

Comment: m_ip = 224.0.1.0
port = 1234